# Neo4j deployment on Private Cloud

Tags: neo4j, cloud

We are looking to deploy Neo4j enterprise version on private cloud. With this we are looking to have an administrative utility that allows to setup the Neo4j cluster quickly and allows to manage the life cycle of Neo4j instances in cluster with features like auto-scalability, failover handling etc. Something similar to GrapheneDb (http://www.graphenedb.com) but that can be deployed on private cloud. Can someone please guide what are the options available to have Neo4j deployed in private cloud like OpenStack and have the above said administrative capabilities?

Many Thanks in advance.